# How to run multiple threads for api calls in android properly?

Tags: android, multithreading

I have multiple API calls in each of the 3 threads.But when huge data is sent through these API calls, app ran slower and some times even API response failure.Is there any better way to perform this task or sequentially run these thread if possible.

I have tried using Async task too but did not work as expected for huge data.

```java
Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {           
        //First Retrofit API calls
        //Second Retrofit API calls
    }
});

Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Third Retrofit API call
        //Fourth Retrofit API call
    }
});

Thread thread3 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {   
    //Fifth Retrofit API call
    //Sixth Retrofit API call
    }
});

thread1.start();
thread2.start();
thread3.start();
```

Comment: RxJava is a good go-to for threading, Apis and works well with Retrofit http://reactivex.io/

Comment: Hey if you want a parallel call then use THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR with asyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add RxJava in your app:gradle

```
android {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.6'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
    ...
}
```

2. Wrap each api call with RxJava or use Retrofit for your api calls.
3. Use Observable.Zip function:

```
Observable.zip(
/*first api call observable*/, 
/*second api call observable etc*/, 
BiFunction<
    /*first api call response*/, 
    /*second api call response*/, 
    /*result of function below*/> { result_of_first_call, result_of_second_call ->
        //do something with result
    }).subscribe {
        //update your UI, etc
    }
```

See: https://medium.com/@nicolas.duponchel/rx-java-for-beginners-8b7c1e7bfc44